# Botón en la cabecera de un GridView

Tags: gridview, devexpress

Necesito pasar el boton de nuevo desde la columna de comandos a la cabecera, ya que al cliente no le agrada que se repita y lo quiere una única vez.

Le he dado mil vueltas y no encuentro la manera de mantenerlo en la tabla sin ser parte de las filas...

Os dejo el código a continuación:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="gvNivelInformaticoUs" runat="server" Width="99%" ClientInstanceName="gvNivelInformaticoUs"
    KeyFieldName="id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Settings-HorizontalScrollBarMode="Hidden" OnRowInserting="gvNivelInformaticoUs_RowInserting"
    OnRowUpdating="gvNivelInformaticoUs_RowUpdating" OnRowValidating="gvNivelInformaticoUs_RowValidating" OnRowDeleting="gvNivelInformaticoUs_RowDeleting" OnDataBinding="gvNivelInformaticoUs_DataBinding">
    <Columns>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="<%$ Resources: Recursos, Denominacion %>" FieldName="nombre_txt" VisibleIndex="0">
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="<%$ Resources: Recursos, nivel %>" FieldName="nivel_txt" VisibleIndex="0">
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>

        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption=" " FieldName="nivel" VisibleIndex="0" Visible="false">
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>


        <dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn Name="columnaEdicion" Width="90" ButtonType="Image" UpdateButton-Image-Url="../img/UPDATE_CA.png" CancelButton-Image-Url="../img/Cancel_CA.png">
            <EditButton Visible="true" Image-Url="../img/edit.png"></EditButton>
            <NewButton Visible="true" Image-Url="../img/add.png"></NewButton>
            <DeleteButton Visible="true" Image-Url="../img/Cancel_CA.gif"></DeleteButton>
        </dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn>
    </Columns>
    <Templates>
        <EditForm>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                <label><%= Resources.Recursos.Nombre%>*:</label>
                <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="TxtNombreInformatica" MaxLength="250" CssClass="form-control col-sm-8" runat="server" ValueField="id" TextField="Nombre" OnInit="TxtNombreInformatica_Init"></dxe:ASPxTextBox>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                <label><%= Resources.Recursos.nivel%>*:</label>
                <dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="CmbNivelInformatica" CssClass="form-control col-sm-8" runat="server" ValueField="id" TextField="Nombre" OnInit="CmbNivelInformatica_Init"></dxe:ASPxComboBox>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                <span class="separador">&nbsp;</span>
                <dxwgv:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement1" runat="server" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton" />
                <dxwgv:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement2" runat="server" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton" />
            </div>


        </EditForm>
    </Templates>
</dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías dejar el boton por fuera del grid en cualquier parte y en el evento click del boton del lado del cliente usas :

```
gvNivelInformaticoUs.AddNewRow
```

Aqui unos links de referencia al Grid de DevExpress

https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientGridView.AddNewRow.method

Aqui otro ejemplo con la misma tecnica pero con el boton dentro de la cabecera de una columna :

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q339207/aspxgridview-how-to-add-the-new-button-to-a-command-column-header

Comment: He conseguido meterlo en la cabecera, ahora lo colgare. Pero tu respuesta tambien me es valida.